# SQL Query to Rails 3 for average user ratings

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a rails app that rates restaurants on specific dimensions using the letsrate gem. I'd like to calculate the average of all ratings for each restaurant and display it to the user in an array on the index page.

My SQL query would look like this -

```
select avg(stars) from RESTAURANTS r, RATES rs
where rs.rateable_id = r.id
group by r.name;
```

The array in my index looks like -

```
<% @restaurants.each do |restaurant| %>
<li>
    <a href="<%=restaurant_path(restaurant) %>" >
        <div class="left">
            <h2 class="name"><%= restaurant.name %></h2>
            <h3 class="location"><%= restaurant.location %></h3>
        </div>
        <div class="right">
            <h4 class="rate">AVERAGE RATING</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </a>
</li>
<% end %>
```

Wondering how I would translate the sql query into rails to display the averages in the array.

Answer (score 1):

If you setup your relations correctly, this should work. If not I'll help you fix them.

**Edit**

In your Restaurant Controller:

```
class RestaurantController > ApplicationController

  def index
    @restaurants = Rate.joins(:restaurant).select("avg(rates.stars) as res_avg, restaurants.name, restaurant.location").group("restaurants.name")
  end
end
```

In your Restaurant index.html.erb:

```
<% @restaurants.each do |restaurant| %>
<li>
  <a href="<%=restaurant_path(restaurant.id) %>" >
    <div class="left">
        <h2 class="name"><%= restaurant.name %></h2>
        <h3 class="location"><%= restaurant.location %></h3>
    </div>
    <div class="right">
        <h4 class="rate"><%= restaurant.res_avg %></h4>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
  </a>
</li>
<% end %>
```

**Edit2**
If you want to re-use this query declare it in a scope on the model.

```
class Restaurant < ActiveRecord::Base
  #all your model code
  scope :avg_restaurant_rates, joins(:rate).select("avg(rates.stars) as res_avg, restaurants.name, restaurants.location").group("restaurants.name")
end
```

Comment: Thank you! So here's where I'm still confused, how do I now call this in the index view to display the average for each restaurant? Where I'm a little rusty is do I define a model method and add this in there then call that method in the array?

Comment: This works but it breaks <%=restaurant_path(restaurant) %>, is there a better way to handle this than defining it in the controller? Suppose I want to reuse the average rating in a show view, in that case would this be better suited as a helper method?

Comment: The rails path helpers need the id value to determine the path.  I've updated the code to reflect the required change.  To reuse this query I'd write as a scope in the Restaurant Model.

Comment: I think you're missing a plural on restaurant.location? Some RDBMS will require both not aggregated columns in the select to be grouped also